# Function uses method from different class than it should

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

I have TestController, hich doesn't have its own model. I use various model inside it, among them Trunk Model. I have my function "call", that wants to use method "singlePckgCall" from Trunk Model. Until here everything goes okay.

[image: TestController]

This method, which I'm trying to use, uses another method, placed below - "callSingleNumber".

[image]

And then it stops, and sends me an error page:

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
>
> Calling unknown method:
>   frontend\controllers\TestController::callSingleNumber()

I have no idea why it wants to call a method from TestController, instead on Trunk Model, as I want it to do. In result, it doesn't see such a method, because it exists in another class. I tried to rewrite this part manually once more, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `singlePckgCall` statically, so inside `singlePckgCall` method `$this` instance is not available.

To solve your problem, you can

1) call `callSingleNumber` statically in `singlePckgCall` :

```
$action_id_array[$key] = self::callSingleNumber($numery[$i], TRUE);
```

at row 52

2) create an instance of Trunk class, so $this is available in `singlePckgCall`:

```
$instance = new Trunk();
$instance->singlePckgCall($numery);
```

Comment: You should use `static` instead of `self`. See [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)